Why does SVM have a worse decision boundary than Logistic Regression?
I've run both SVM with Polynomial kernel with a degree of 3 and Logistic Regression with transformed features by PolynomialFeatures with the same degree of 3 on the default scikit-learn's Moons dataset. Decision boundaries turned out to be as follows:

I cannot wrap my head around as to why the SVM underperforms compared to the logistic regression. Might that be due to the fact that we need to respect the margin between support vectors? I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

How did you set the different hyperparameters ?

@LucasMorin hyperparameters have been chosen by default. Higher order polynomials tend to not change, if not worsen, the decision boundary

scikit learn has some regularisation by default, maybe it is what kills the square terms.
